# Formatting an external hard drive from HFS to NTFS/exFAT

Tags: partitioning, backup, external-hard-drive, ntfs, hfs+

I have a 2TB external hard drive which I formatted to HFS to store Mac backups since 2014. I also made a 200GB exFAT partition so that it would work with Windows. So currently there is 1.8GB HFS partition with about 1.1TB data on it and an almost full 200GB exFAT partition.

I am planning to convert the entire drive to exFAT as I will not be using Mac in the future.

How do I convert the HFS partition to exFAT without erasing the data ?

I do not have access to another hard drive due to current Covid lockdown. I am not too confident about my internet connection, so 1TB upload/download to cloud seems difficult to do. If any file is corrupt, it is quite possible that the whole copy process will fail.

Are any other options available ?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I convert the HFS partition to exFAT without erasing the data ?

You can't. You'll need to temporarily store the data elsewhere, format the disk as you want, and then copy it back.

> 1TB upload/download to cloud seems difficult to do

A decent backup service should be able to automatically resume where it left off, so a potential interruption or disconnect part way through shouldn't lose too much time...

Integrity checks *should* also be part of a backup service's offering, and depnding on your choice, it could be something that you have more insight into, or can do yourself.

> Are any other options available?

Aside from A) offload to other local storage, or B) offload to cloud storage?

Unfortunately not, sorry. If you want to keep the data, you *must* offload it before formatting the disk.

If your data compresses well, or is already partially backed-up elsewhere, then you could potentially reduce the required temporary storage capacity.

---

It's also with noting that an external hard disk from 2014 (now ~6 years old) might not be the most reliable going forwards - have you considered purchasing a new external disk as part of the "*ongoing maintenance*" of your system instead of repurposing it? It could become a backup disk.

Comment: Thanks !  The hard drive is actually new, I just copied old data on it. It was a pretty painful process back then due to random copy failures, hence I am hesitant to do it again. But it looks like I don't have any other option.

Answer (score 1):

*..1.8GB HFS partition with about 1.1TB data on it and an almost full 200GB exFAT partition.*

1) Shrink the HFS partition down 600GB, and expand the exFAT by 600 GB.
2) Move 600 GB of files from HFS to exFAT.

3) Repeat lines 1 and 2 above.